# Datatable Merge Formatting

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

[image]

I had attached 2 datatable by using merge datatables I am not able to format these 2 tables ?

Code :-

```
 DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();
            dtAll.Merge(dt1);
            dtAll.NewRow();
            dtAll.Merge(dt);
```

I want the highlighted red potion above the attached table please provide me with solution.

Comment: Could you please format your question more properly (including the image)? Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Issue resolved ..